# Making database results array into variables php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make database array into variables to insert into another function, but I keep getting 'Undefined variable'. I would greatly appreciate it if anybody can guide me in the right direction.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE start_day = '".$currentdate."'  ";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {

       $row ['name'] = $name;
       $row ['email'] = $email;
       $row ['bID'] = $bID;
       $row ['start_time'] = $start_time;
       $row ['end_time'] = $end_time;
      $row ['start_day'] = $start_day;
    MailReminder::sendMail($name , $email, $bID, $start_time,$endtime    
  ,$start_day);



    }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Which is your **Undefined variable**?

Comment: it says name, email, bID, start_time, end_time ,start_day

Comment: Swap the vars. `$row ['name'] = $name;` should be `$name = $row ['name'];`

Comment: This doesn’t need any “extra variables” ... you can just use `$row['name']` etc. directly inside the method call.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need to do is extract a database result row to variables with corresponding names you can use php's "[extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)" method.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row)
    MailReminder::sendMail($name , $email, $bID, $start_time, $endtime, $start_day);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Assigning elements of an array to variables should be done as below:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

       $name = $row ['name'];
       $email = $row ['email'];
       $bID = $row ['bID'];
       $start_time = $row ['start_time'];
       $end_time = $row ['end_time'];
       $start_day = $row ['start_day'];

       MailReminder::sendMail($name , $email, $bID, $start_time,$endtime ,$start_day);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable assignements are wrong, in PHP you assign a value to variable like this:

```
$myVariable = 'myValue'; // Correct
'myValue' = $myVariable; // Not correct, will not work
```

So your code must be like that:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $name = $row ['name'];
  $email = $row ['email'];
  $bID = $row ['bID'];
  $start_time = $row ['start_time'];
  $end_time = $row ['end_time'];
  $start_day = $row ['start_day'];
  MailReminder::sendMail($name , $email, $bID, $start_time, $endtime, $start_day);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Faster method where you don't even need the variables:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  MailReminder::sendMail($row ['name'] , $row ['email'], $row ['bID'], $row ['start_time'], $row ['end_time'], $row ['start_day']);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```